# ¿Cómo asignar un filegroup a un Usuario? SQL Server 18

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, sql-server-2017

Generé un Filegroup llamado "grupoArchivos_users" para manejar cuotas en los usuarios de la base de datos, el problema viene al intentar asignar la cuota al usuario pues muestra un error de sintaxis cerca del "DEFAULT":
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tú a un usuario le puedes dar un default schema según la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). No tiene opción para definirle un filegroup porque no tiene sentido hacerlo.

A una base de datos le puedes definir (de nuevo según la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15&tabs=sqlpool)) los filegroups con sus respectivos archivos. No al usuario. Un usuario es un conjunto de credenciales para acceder a unos recursos que definas.